# Android AndEngine Button Remains highlighted

Tags: android, andengine

I am using `andengine` and I have some sprites that change color when pressed.

On `Action_Down` I use the `changeColor` method and on `ActionUp` I turn it back to normal.

The problem with this is that when I press my button/sprite it changes color and when I move my finger outside the object and take it up it no longer goes into the `Action_Up` case.

Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **Action_Move** case and test for when the finger moves off the button and do the same action you do in **Action_Up**

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't work.I ended up putting a touch listener on the scene also.