# Using an Android Drawable as an AndEngine HUD

Tags: android, andengine, xml-drawable

I'm trying to create an AndEngine HUD that will sit on top of a TMXTiledMap (bear with me, I'm very new to AndEngine). To keep things simple at first, I have a simple rectangle created via Android drawables. The idea is that this will sit at the bottom center of the screen and never move, even as the map underneath it is moved in various directions. For now, all I want to do is get that rectangle to show up. Later on I'll add other functionality to the rectangle.

My drawable is created like this:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:radius="7dp" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#343434"
            android:endColor="#17171717"
            android:angle="270"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:type="linear" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

And I have it pulled into a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_bkgrnd" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And then finally, here is where I try to pull it in as a HUD:

```
rect = new HUD();
ITouchArea container = (ITouchArea) findViewById(R.id.container);
this.rect.registerTouchArea(container);
rect.attachChild((IEntity) container);
```

As you can see, I'm doing a lot of casting to satisfy AndEngine, but when I run this, the map is totally screwed up. Am I going about this correctly? Is my casting incorrect? (or maybe both!).

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Based on the code that Jong and 正宗白布鞋 suggested below, I've adjusted my Java code as follows:

```
this.atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
this.atlas.load();
ITextureRegion drawable = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(atlas, getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.myDrawable, 0, 0);
rect.attachChild(new Sprite(0, 0, drawable, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()));
```

At this point, I'm still just trying to get this to appear on the screen. I'll adjust size and location later.

Everything compiles and runs without error, however my screen is just a total mess.

As you can see, I had to make a couple of small adjustments to the constructor arguments to get AndEngine to accept my instantiations. Not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

The other issue that I see in this code is that it appears to me that this code is just going to place an inactive shape on my screen. I know that in my original post, I said that my immediate goal is to make this rectangle show up, but I think that it has to show up as a registered touch area since it will ultimately be something with controls on it that need to respond to user commands. Sorry if I overly minimized what I am trying to do.

I'm still not getting this. Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: I think your casting is incorrect. Your R.id.container is a Android LinearLayout, but you cast it to AndEngine ITouchArea. Since you have your 'shape' xml defined in your /drawable already, you may use it and some AndEngine functions (ex: BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.CreateFromResource) to create your TextureRegion or Sprite, and then attach it to your HUD.

Comment: 1. you forget to call this.atlas.load().  2. you can override the sprite class and implement your onAreaTouched method.

Comment: Thank you. I added this.atlas.load(), which now changes the screen, but the screen is a mess. I don't know how to override the sprite class in this way.

Comment: load should be called after textureregion setup completed. there are some examples showing how to override, ex: line 81 at [link](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TouchDragExample.java)

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but I'm totally stuck. Are there any AndEngine experts out there who can take a look at this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast `LinearLayout` to `ITouchArea`, `ITouchArea` is an interface implemented by AndEngine classes only.

Like 正宗白布鞋 suggested, you should use the `createFromResource` method of `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory`.

You can use this code:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(sizeX, sizeY, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
TextureRegion drawable = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(atlas, getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.drawableId, 0, 0);
rect.attachChild(new Sprite(x, y, drawable));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want your sprite to respond to touch events, you can register it as a touch area in your `rect` HUD.

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(x, y, drawable, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pTouchEvent, final float pX, final float pY) {
        //Do what you want here
    }
}
rect.registerTouchArea(sprite);
rect.attachChild(sprite);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement your suggestion, but am not quite resolving this. I edited my OP above with what I did and further questions. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you. The part that isn't working is the BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.  I keep getting a NullBitmapException when I run this. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: It's probably happening because AndEngine fails to load your drawable. Test the drawable on a regular activity

Comment: The activity seems to be working just fine. I can start an activity with this as its content and it displays perfectly. For now, it's just a very simple gradient background. I'm trying to get the hud set up before I invest any time in making the drawable. I started a new post on this to just focus on the null exception, so if you have a few minutes and don't mind, check that one out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem several days ago, and I couldn't find a proper answer. So now that I've gathered information from different sources, here is how I dealt with this.

AFAIK, it appears that the method `createFromResource(atlas, getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.drawableId, 0, 0)` from `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory` cannot deal with XML drawable (such as `<shape>...</shape>`).
Indeed, when I was only displaying a colored rectangle, everything was fine - and I *think* with a PNG file too -, but when I tried to create a `Sprite` from my XML drawable, I always got a `NullBitmapException` when the drawing happened.

Steps I took:

- Convert drawable resource to `Drawable`
- Convert `Drawable` to `Bitmap` ([Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap))
- Convert `Bitmap` to `TextureRegion` (This is where I used [this](https://github.com/edbartley/AndEngine---Texture-Source-From-Bitmap))
- Create a `Sprite` from the `TextureRegion` (or two for selected/unselected, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067627/change-image-of-sprite-andengine))
- Attach the `Sprite` to the game's `HUD`

So, with code:

**Convert drawable resource `TextureRegion`**

```
/**
 * Takes a drawable, and converts it to a TextureRegion.
 * @param context
 * @param resId the drawable ID
 * @param textureSizeX width for our TextureRegion
 * @param textureSizeY height for our TextureRegion
 * @return a TextureRegion from the drawable
 */
public static TextureRegion textureRegionFromDrawable(BaseGameActivity context, int resId, int textureSizeX, int textureSizeY) {
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureSource source = new BitmapTextureAtlasTextureSource(bitmap);
    BitmapTextureAtlas textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(context.getTextureManager(), textureSizeX, textureSizeY);
    textureAtlas.addTextureAtlasSource(source, 0, 0);
    textureAtlas.load();
    TextureRegion textureRegion = (TextureRegion) TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(textureAtlas, source, 0, 0);
    return textureRegion;
}
// Drawable to Bitmap
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

**The utility intermediary class**

```
public class BitmapTextureAtlasTextureSource extends BaseTextureAtlasSource implements IBitmapTextureAtlasSource {
    private final int[] mColors;
    public BitmapTextureAtlasTextureSource(Bitmap pBitmap) {
        super(0, 0, pBitmap.getWidth(), pBitmap.getHeight());
        mColors = new int[mTextureWidth * mTextureHeight];
        for (int y = 0; y < mTextureHeight; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mTextureWidth; ++x) {
                mColors[x + y * mTextureWidth] = pBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(Config pBitmapConfig) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(mColors, mTextureWidth, mTextureHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    @Override
    public IBitmapTextureAtlasSource deepCopy() {
        return new BitmapTextureAtlasTextureSource(Bitmap.createBitmap(mColors, mTextureWidth, mTextureHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(Config pBitmapConfig, boolean pMutable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Create two `Sprite` from the `TextureRegion`s** (I wanted 2 states for my button: selected/unselected), and attach them to the `HUD`

```
int textureSizeX = 512, textureSizeY = 512;
TextureRegion textureDefault = AndEngineUtils.textureRegionFromDrawable(activity, R.drawable.custom_menu_button, textureSizeX, textureSizeY);
TextureRegion textureSelected = AndEngineUtils.textureRegionFromDrawable(activity, R.drawable.custom_menu_button_selected, textureSizeX, textureSizeY);
mGameHUD = new HUD();

// 2 sprites for selected and unselected
final Sprite buttonUnselected, buttonSelected ;
buttonSelected = new Sprite(0, 0, textureSelected, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
buttonSelected.setVisible(false);

buttonUnselected = new Sprite(0, 0, textureDefault, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Change button
            buttonSelected.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // reset button
            this.setVisible(true);
            buttonSelected.setVisible(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    }
};
mGameHUD.attachChild(buttonSelected);
mGameHUD.attachChild(buttonUnselected);
mGameHUD.registerTouchArea(buttonUnselected);
camera.setHUD(mGameHUD);
```

We can also make use of `scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(touchListener)` in order for an "unwanted" sliding gesture - until outside of the button - to take effet to reset the button color (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881419/android-andengine-button-remains-highlighted)).

I have just begun using `AndEngine` and I am not yet familiar with best practices, so feel free to correct me.